# .NET WCF Permission to access port in Win Vista/7

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I have written a program in vb.net which uses WCF to communicate with another program. It uses a particular port. When I run the program I get message :

```
"HTTP could not register URL http://+:6700/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace."
```

After doing some research I figured that to solve the issue either I run my program in elevated mode (as admin) all the time or I allow communication through my url/port.

I wanted that when I run my program for the first time, I could run another small exe or bat file which will automatically add the required port info into the httpnamespace. This should solve it I guess.

Someone recommended: `netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:port/uri user=DOMAIN\user`

But here getting `domain\user` would be tedious. So what should I do ?

Can someone give me a small vb.net code to add this info in http namespace or should I run a bat file with text shown above.

Help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Cheers,
GR

Comment: Care to explain you remark about getting the domain user to be tedious?

Comment: Did you ever come to a conclusion on the best route to handle this ?